# Add custom parametres into google map Icon

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, icons, google-maps-markers

I need the icons in the array, and after comparing to take an array of icons, as getting data via JSON, and accordingly can not tell them there as an object.

Create icons and put them array:

```
EMarkers = [];
var icon1e = {
                nameIco: icon1e,
                url: "./icon/sight.png",
                size: new google.maps.Size(16, 16),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(8, 8),
                };

                EMarkers.push(icon1e);

                var icon2e = {
                nameIco: icon2e,
                url: "./icon/museum21.png",
                size: new google.maps.Size(16, 16),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(8, 8),
                };

                EMarkers.push(icon2e);

                var icon3e = {
                nameIco: icon3e,
                url: "./icon/hram.png",
                size: new google.maps.Size(16, 16),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(8, 8),
                };

                EMarkers.push(icon3e);
```

But custom options in the object Icon will not be transmitted, as well as marker.

```
jQuery.getJSON(url, function (json) {

        jQuery.each(json, function(i, entry){
            var _id = entry.event_id;
            var _point = new google.maps.LatLng(entry.options.lat,entry.options.lng);

            jQuery.each(EMarkers, function(idx, data){
                if (data.nameIco == entry.options.icon){ 
                    entry.options.icon = data;
                }           
            });


            createMarker( _point, entry.options);

        });

});

 function createMarker(point, options){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: point, 
            map: map,
            icon: options.icon,
            title: options.title,
            id: options.id
        });
    }
```

The problem is that I can not get to using JSON icons for marker only as a string, and the only way I can see to get the objects created from an array, but how to get out of it the desired value?

Answer (score 0):

the objects are available **after** they have been created , so you can't use references to them when you create them.

This would have the desired result:

```
var icon1e = {
             url: "./icon/sight.png",
             size: new google.maps.Size(16, 16),
             anchor: new google.maps.Point(8, 8),
            };

 icon1e.nameIco = icon1e;
```

...but I wouldn't suggest it, it creates a circular reference.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but your comparison may fail in any case, because transporting instances of classes like `google.maps.Size` usually is not possible via JSON.

You better use a string for `options.icon`(maybe you already do it) of the JSON-items(e.g. "icon3e") and use an object instead of an array for `EMarkers`, than you may easily compare `entry.options.icon` and the key of `EMarkers`

```
EMarkers = {
  icon1e = {
                url: "./icon/sight.png",
                size: new google.maps.Size(16, 16),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(8, 8),
                },
  icon2e = {
                url: "./icon/museum21.png",
                size: new google.maps.Size(16, 16),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(8, 8),
                },
  icon3e = {
                url: "./icon/hram.png",
                size: new google.maps.Size(16, 16),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(8, 8),
                }
};
```

.....

jQuery.getJSON(url, function (json) {

```
    jQuery.each(json, function(i, entry){
        var _id = entry.event_id;
        var _point = new google.maps.LatLng(entry.options.lat,entry.options.lng);

        jQuery.each(EMarkers, function(key){
            if (key === entry.options.icon){ 
                entry.options.icon = data;
            }           
        });


        createMarker( _point, entry.options);

    });
```

});

The inner loop may be removed in this case:
jQuery.getJSON(url, function (json) {

```
    jQuery.each(json, function(i, entry){
        var _id = entry.event_id;
        var _point = new google.maps.LatLng(entry.options.lat,entry.options.lng);
        entry.options.icon=EMarkers[entry.options.icon]
        createMarker( _point, entry.options);

    });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, you're right about the format string:

The decision was simple: the variable name must be a string, then to compare it

Instead:

```
var icon1e = {
                nameIco: icon1e,
                url: "./icon/sight.png",
                size: new google.maps.Size(16, 16),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(8, 8),
                };
```

Use:

```
var icon1e = {
                nameIco: "icon1e",
                url: "./icon/sight.png",
                size: new google.maps.Size(16, 16),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(8, 8),
                };
```

And it works :)